# Proper indentation for multiline strings?

Tags: python, string

What is the proper indentation for Python multiline strings within a function?

```
    def method():
        string = """line one
line two
line three"""
```

or

```
    def method():
        string = """line one
        line two
        line three"""
```

or something else?

It looks kind of weird to have the string hanging outside the function in the first example.

Comment: Docstrings are treated [specially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534246/docstring-processing-tools-following-pep-257): any indent of the first line is removed; the smallest common indent taken over all other non-blank lines is removed from them all. Other than that, multiline string literals in Python are unfortunately what-you-see-is-what-you-get in terms of whitespace: all characters between the string delimiters become part of the string, including indentation that, with Python reading instincts, looks like it should be measured from the indent of the line where the literal starts.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev The processing tool performs this task (and that largely depends on your choice of processing tool). `method.__doc__` isn't modified by Python itself any more than any other `str` literal.

Answer (score 536, accepted):

You probably want to line up with the `"""`

```
def foo():
    string = """line one
             line two
             line three"""
```

Since the newlines and spaces are included in the string itself, you will have to postprocess it. If you don't want to do that and you have a whole lot of text, you might want to store it separately in a text file. If a text file does not work well for your application and you don't want to postprocess, I'd probably go with

```
def foo():
    string = ("this is an "
              "implicitly joined "
              "string")
```

If you want to postprocess a multiline string to trim out the parts you don't need, you should consider the [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module or the technique for postprocessing docstrings presented in [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

```
def trim(docstring):
    import sys
    if not docstring:
        return ''
    # Convert tabs to spaces (following the normal Python rules)
    # and split into a list of lines:
    lines = docstring.expandtabs().splitlines()
    # Determine minimum indentation (first line doesn't count):
    indent = sys.maxint
    for line in lines[1:]:
        stripped = line.lstrip()
        if stripped:
            indent = min(indent, len(line) - len(stripped))
    # Remove indentation (first line is special):
    trimmed = [lines[0].strip()]
    if indent < sys.maxint:
        for line in lines[1:]:
            trimmed.append(line[indent:].rstrip())
    # Strip off trailing and leading blank lines:
    while trimmed and not trimmed[-1]:
        trimmed.pop()
    while trimmed and not trimmed[0]:
        trimmed.pop(0)
    # Return a single string:
    return '\n'.join(trimmed)
```

Comment: It's good to have the same level of indentation for each line of text in the string. But that means that the lines of text should be a single indentation level in (4 columns), not starting at some arbitrary many-columns-along position from the previous line.

Comment: @bignose, I do not see how that requirement helps to keep code cleaner or more readable or has any particular advantage.

Comment: This is the ‘hanging indent’ style of line continuation. It is prescribed in PEP8 for purposes like function definitions and long if statements, though not mentioned for multiline strings. Personally this is one place I refuse to follow PEP8 (and use 4-space indenting instead), as I strongly dislike hanging indents, which for me obscure the proper structure of the program.

Comment: @Mike Where is this usage of string described ? string = ("this is an "
              "implicitly joined "
              "string")

Comment: @buffer, in 3.1.2 of the official tutorial ("Two string literals next to each other are automatically concatenated...") and in the language reference.

Comment: The second form with automatic string concatenation doesn't include newlines, so you need to add \n for every line. This method is also very unnatural to insert blank lines (you need to have "\n\n" lines). I wish there is support similar to the the bash's here document with leading tabs suppressed (<<-END).

Comment: *The second form with automatic string concatenation doesn't include newline* It's a feature.

Comment: See also "Implicit string literal concatenation considered harmful?" by  Guido van Rossum (some random guy...) http://lwn.net/Articles/551426/

Comment: It's worth recognizing that, while implicit concatenation is a misfeature that Python would be better for not having, this particular use isn't particularly hard to see or understand and isn't especially error-prone.

Comment: +1 for the `("this is an "` ... technique. it works as a docstring. if you need newline, you can use `("this is an "    "\n"`

Comment: The `trim()` function as specified in PEP257 is implemented in the standard library as [`inspect.cleandoc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc).

Comment: I found that the 2nd example to work in python 3, I had to add also trailing \ to the end of the lines. Otherwise I get "unexpected indent" errors.

Comment: @MrTJ It works for me in Python 3 -- did you have the parens?

Comment: +1 to @bobince 's comment about rejecting "hanging indents" here... Especially because if you change the variable name from `string` to `text` or anything of a different length, then you now need to update the indentation of *literally every single line of the multiline string* just to get it to match up with the `"""` properly. Indentation strategy should not complicate future refactors/maintenance, and it's one of the places that PEP really fails

Comment: While this is a solid answer, do yourselves a favor and take a look at @wihlke's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112903/760306) for the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 385):

The [`textwrap.dedent`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) function allows one to start with **correct indentation in the source**, and then strip it from the text before use.

The trade-off, as noted by some others, is that this is an extra function call on the literal; take this into account when deciding where to place these literals in your code.

```python
import textwrap

def frobnicate(param):
    """ Frobnicate the scrognate param.

        The Weebly-Ruckford algorithm is employed to frobnicate
        the scrognate to within an inch of its life.
        """
    prepare_the_comfy_chair(param)
    log_message = textwrap.dedent("""\
            Prepare to frobnicate:
            Here it comes...
                Any moment now.
            And: Frobnicate!""")
    weebly(param, log_message)
    ruckford(param)
```

The trailing `\` in the log message literal is to ensure that line break isn't in the literal; that way, the literal doesn't start with a blank line, and instead starts with the next full line.

The return value from `textwrap.dedent` is the input string with **all common leading whitespace indentation removed** on each line of the string. So the above `log_message` value will be:

```
Prepare to frobnicate:
Here it comes...
    Any moment now.
And: Frobnicate!
```

Comment: While this is a reasonable solution and nice to know, doing something like this inside a frequently called function could prove to be a disaster.

Comment: @haridsv Why would that be a disaster?

Comment: @jtmoulia: A better description than disaster would be "inefficient" because the result of the `textwrap.dedent()` call is a constant value, just like its input argument.

Comment: @haridsv the origin of that disaster/inefficiency is *definining* a constant string **inside** a frequently called function. Possible to trade the per-call constant definition for a per-call lookup. That way the *dedent* preprocessing would run *only once*. A relevant question may be http://stackoverflow.com/q/15495376/611007 It lists ideas to avoid defining the constant per each call. Albeit alternatives seems to require a lookup. Still, various ways to find the favorable place to store it are attempted. For example: `def foo: return foo.x` then next line `foo.x = textwrap.dedent("bar")`.

Comment: I guess it would be inefficient if the string is intended for logging that is only enabled in debug mode, and goes unused otherwise. But then why log a multiline string literal anyway? So it's hard to find a real-life example where the above would be inefficient (i.e. where it slows down the program considerably), because whatever is consuming these strings is going to be slower.

Answer (score 176):

Use [`inspect.cleandoc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc):

```py
import inspect

def method():
    string = inspect.cleandoc("""
        line one
        line two
        line three""")
```

What [`inspect.cleandoc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc) and [`textwrap.dedent()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) both do:

- count leading spaces of least indented non-empty line
- remove that count of spaces from each non-empty line

What [`inspect.cleandoc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc) additionally does:

- remove leading and trailing `\n` from the result

> **Note:** It's good practice to indent logical blocks of code under its related context to clarify the structure. E.g. the multi-line string belonging to the variable `string`.

Answer (score 42):

One option which seems to missing from the other answers (only mentioned deep down in a comment by naxa) is the following:

```
def foo():
    string = ("line one\n"          # Add \n in the string
              "line two"  "\n"      # Add "\n" after the string
              "line three\n")
```

This will allow proper aligning, join the lines implicitly, and still keep the line shift which, for me, is one of the reasons why I would like to use multiline strings anyway.

It doesn't require any postprocessing, but you need to manually add the `\n` at any given place that you want the line to end. Either inline or as a separate string after. The latter is easier to copy-paste in.

Comment: Note that this is an example of an implicitly joined string, not a multiline string.

Comment: @trk, it's multiline in the sense that the string contains newlines (aka multiple lines), but yes it uses joining to circumvent the formatting issues the OP had.

Comment: This looks like the best answer for me. But so far I don't understand why does python needs triple quotes operator if they result in a hard-to-read code.

Comment: Just having to consider how to return a literal multi-line string for the first time now. I don't want to have to support them with post processing or anything and I just want the   literal to read nicely. This version is by far the simplest and most readable and when formatted with `black` (first string segment on a new line and align at the next indent not after the parenthesis) comes out nicer than shown in the answer with more line length available for longer strings.

Answer (score 22):

Some more options.  In Ipython with pylab enabled, dedent is already in the namespace.  I checked and it is from matplotlib.  Or it can be imported with:

```
from matplotlib.cbook import dedent
```

In documentation it states that it is faster than the textwrap equivalent one and in my tests in ipython it is indeed 3 times faster on average with my quick tests.   It also has the benefit that it discards any leading blank lines this allows you to be flexible in how you construct the string:

```
"""
line 1 of string
line 2 of string
"""

"""\
line 1 of string
line 2 of string
"""

"""line 1 of string
line 2 of string
"""
```

Using the matplotlib dedent on these three examples will give the same sensible result.  The textwrap dedent function will have a leading blank line with 1st example.

Obvious disadvantage is that textwrap is in standard library while matplotlib is external module.

Some tradeoffs here... the dedent functions make your code more readable where the strings get defined, but require processing later to get the string in usable format.  In docstrings it is obvious that you should use correct indentation as most uses of the docstring will do the required processing.

When I need a non long string in my code I find the following admittedly ugly code where I let the long string drop out of the enclosing indentation.  Definitely fails on "Beautiful is better than ugly.", but one could argue that it is simpler and more explicit than the dedent alternative.

```
def example():
    long_string = '''\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.\
'''
    return long_string

print example()
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want a quick&easy solution and save yourself from typing newlines, you could opt for a list instead, e.g.:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    string = '\n'.join([
        'first line of very long string and',
        'second line of the same long thing and',
        'third line of ...',
        'and so on...',
        ])
    print(string)
    return
```

Comment: While this isn't the best approach, I've used it from time to time. If you *do* use it, you should use a tuple instead of a list, since it's not going to be modified before being joined.

Comment: Note that if the purpose is printing, then setting the `sep` argument to `'\n'` in the print call is cleaner than using `join`.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer

```
    def method():
        string = \
"""\
line one
line two
line three\
"""
```

or

```
    def method():
        string = """\
line one
line two
line three\
"""
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, because the question explicitly states that the indentation (within the function) matters.

Comment: @bignose The question said "It looks kind of weird" not disallowed to use.

Comment: how would i accomplish this without the ugly indentation?

Comment: @lfender6445 well, maybe you can place all these strings to a separate file from other codes...

Answer (score 3):

My two cents, escape the end of line to get the indents:

```
def foo():
    return "{}\n"\
           "freq: {}\n"\
           "temp: {}\n".format( time, freq, temp )
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a simple 1-liner to **remove/correct the identation level** of the docstring for printing, **without making it look untidy**,  for example by making it "hang outside the function" within the script.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
import string
def myfunction():

    """
    line 1 of docstring
    line 2 of docstring
    line 3 of docstring"""

print str(string.replace(myfunction.__doc__,'\n\t','\n'))[1:]
```

Obviously, if you're indenting with spaces (e.g. 4) rather than the tab key use something like this instead:

```
print str(string.replace(myfunction.__doc__,'\n    ','\n'))[1:]
```

And you don't need to remove the first character if you like your docstrings to look like this instead:

```
    """line 1 of docstring
    line 2 of docstring
    line 3 of docstring"""

print string.replace(myfunction.__doc__,'\n\t','\n')
```

Comment: This fails on class methods and nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

For strings you can just after process the string. For docstrings you need to after process the function instead. Here is a solution for both that is still readable.

```
class Lstrip(object):
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        import re
        return re.sub('^\n', '', re.sub('\n$', '', re.sub('\n\s+', '\n', other)))

msg = '''
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
      ''' - Lstrip()

print msg

def lstrip_docstring(func):
    func.__doc__ = func.__doc__ - Lstrip()
    return func

@lstrip_docstring
def foo():
    '''
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
    est laborum.
    '''
    pass


print foo.__doc__
```

Comment: Processing docstrings must already process consistent indentation, as [described in PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#handling-docstring-indentation). There are already tools – e.g. [`inspect.cleandoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc) – which do this the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is the good one - with indentation included. 
It is in python style - provides readability for the code.

To display it properly:

```
print string.lstrip()
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest and cleanest way to format triple quote strings so you don't have the extra spaces due to indentation

Comment: This will only delete leading spaces in the first line of a multiline string. It does not help with formatting following lines.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on how you want the text to display. If you want it all to be left-aligned then either format it as in the first snippet or iterate through the lines left-trimming all the space.

Comment: The way docstring-processing tools work is to remove not *all* the space on the left, but *as much* as the first indented line. This strategy is a bit more sophisticated and allows for you to indent and have it respected in the postprocessed string.