# Divide a string into several lines

Tags: python, string

I can make a long string (`my_xml`) like this:

```
elements = Element.objects.all()
my_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n'
my_xml += 'description\n'
my_xml += 'document title\n'
my_xml += 'other_infos\n'
for elt in elements:
    my_xml += elt.title
    my_xml += elt.desc
return HttpResponse(my_xml)
```

Is there another cleaner way to do it instead of repeating "`my_xml +=`" tag?

Comment: Would you happen to be using a webframework here (Django maybe)?

Comment: -1 you should redesign you code.

Comment: Use a multilne string - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings

Comment: @JonClements: Yes exactely, i use Django

Comment: @Drwhite then you should be using a template and rendering that instead...

Comment: @JonClements: if i use template i will render just a string, so i did print it directly with HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your page this way, consider using (following the example given in 
[Proper indentation for Python multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings) )

**edited to make the `xml` line show on the page, and make line breaks work:**

```
elements = Element.objects.all()
my_xml = ('<html type=text/html encoding="utf-8">'
  '&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;<br>'
  'description<br>'
  'document title<br>'
  'other_infos<br>')

for elt in elements:
  my_xml += elt.title + '<br>'
  my_xml += elt.desc + '<br>'

my_xml += '</html>'

return HttpResponse(my_xml)
```

Comment: this is the output (without for loop): description document title other_infos. It seems like not knowing the `<>` and the new line `\n` !

Comment: if i use a template and render my_xml, it know my string but without new line :S

Comment: Replace your `\n` with `<br>` and it will create line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list:

```
elements = Element.objects.all()
xml_parts = ["""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
description
document title
other_infos
"""]
for el in elements:
    xml_parts.append(elt.title)
    xml_parts.append(elt.desc)
return HttpResponse(''.join(xml_parts))
```