# python split statement into multiple lines

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
print "my name is [%s], I like [%s] and I ask question on [%s]" % ("xxx", "python", "stackoverflow")
```

I want to split this LONG line into multiple lines:

```
print
  "my name is [%s]"
  ", I like [%s] "
  "and I ask question on [%s]"
  % ("xxx", "python", "stackoverflow")
```

Can you please provide the right syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper indentation for Python multiline strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use implied line continuation by putting everything within parentheses.  This is the method recommended in [Python's Style Guide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id12):

```
print ("my name is [%s]"
       ", I like [%s] "
       "and I ask question on [%s]"
       % ("xxx", "python", "stackoverflow"))
```

This works because the Python interpreter will concatenate adjacent string literals, so `"foo" 'bar'` becomes `'foobar'`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative style:

```
print "my name is [%s], I like [%s] and I ask question on [%s]" % (
    "xxx", "python", "stackoverflow")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_val = '''"my name is [%s]"
  ", I like [%s] "
  "and I ask question on [%s]"
  % ("xxx", "python", "stackoverflow")'''

print(str_val)
```