# Why are three apostrophes needed for print in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making this Pythagoras Theorem Calculator in Python 3.3.2.

I made print over several lines so that I could make a diagram:

```
print("Welcome to the Pythagoras Theorem Calculator, powered by Python!")
print("Below are the values a, b and c. You will need to input these values after.")
print('''
      | .
      |   .
      |     .
side a|       . side c
      |         .
      |           .
      |_____________.
          side b
      ''')
```

As you can see above, three apostrophes were needed instead of the speech marks. Why is this so? Is it an escape character? (I've tried searching on Google: http://bit.ly/15a4zes)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: This question suggest to me that you should be able to use speech marks: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2504411/945456

Comment: @JeffBridgman: You can, if you use three of them.

Comment: You can use either `'''somestring'''` (I call those single quotes) or `"""somestring"""` (double quotes), but you can't mix and match. `'''somestring"""` doesn't work.

Comment: While "apostrophes" is not incorrect, usually programmers call them "single-quotes" (and the actual `"` quotation marks "double-quotes")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The three quotes allows you to make a string on multiple lines. It avoids you to add `\n` everywhere or doing multiple `print` statements.

Threes quote strings are also <strike>used</strike> **recommended** to make documentation, see the [PEP 257 convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)  (see also comments of this post)

Comment: I'm choosing this answer as it also provides a link and directly answers the question.

Comment: You can make documentation with single-quoted strings too. All you need is a string literal as the first of code in your object (function, class, module).

Comment: Oh really? I learned something today. I must have seen well-documented code everytime since I've never seen function with simple-quoted string at the beginning... Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

They are not needed, they just make it *easier* to produce a multi-line string.

The alternative would be:

```
print('      | .')
print('      |   .')
print('      |     .')
print('side a|       . side c')
print('      |         .')
print('      |           .')
print('      |_____________.')
print('          side b')
```

Note that Python lets you take your pick of `'..'` and `".."` style quotes, whatever better suits your string *contents*.

Comment: Why does it say "EOL while scanning string literal" if I do put speech marks?

Comment: I don't think this answers the original question which I understood to be "Why can I only use `'` and not `"` to produce a multi-line string?"

Comment: @TimTimmy: Perhaps you forgot to clone one?

Answer (score 3):

Three apostrophes (or speech marks) make your string a triple-quoted string.  This allows it to span multiple lines.  Normal strings can not do this.

If you want the same effect with normal strings, you have to put a `'\n'` every time you want a line break (which is a little annoying and also makes your string hard to read).

Answer (score 1):

**The three single** (`'''`) **or double** (`"""`) **quotes** (of course the same at the begin and at the end of string) **allows us to make an *output* on multiple lines without adding explicite the newline character**  (`\n`) **at the end of each line** or without adding a multiple `print` functions in the source code.

**Additional note**:

- Know that **if you don't want to display some newline character at the output**, but you want to use this transparent notation in your source code, **then you can to add the character** `\` **at the end of the line**.

For example in the above case, **if you don't like to display the initial newline** then you can achieve it like this:

```
print('''\
...
```

And one more **small note**:

This works the same for *Python 2* and *Python 3*.