# New line of code in python

Tags: python

I am doing some Python programming, and I have a couple of lines that are longer than 120 chars, which is our maximum line width in our coding style guidelines.

Now I was wondering how to do a line break in python, here is an example:

```
someString = "Here is a [.......] very long text"    # This line is now 130 chars long
```

And I want something like this:

```
someString = "Here is a [...]
    [...] very long text"
```

How can I format my python script like this?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings

Answer (score 2):

Put it in parentheses and split up the lines with open and close quotes - these are automatically concatenated.

```
someString = ("Here is a [...]"
              "[...] very long text")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
someString = "Here is a [...] \
    [...] very long text"
```

or

```
print('Here is a [...]'
      '[...] very long text')
```

or even

```
someString = ('Here is a [...]'
              '[...] very long string')
```

or why not

```
someString = 'Here is a [...]'
someString += '[...] very long string'
```