# Python triple quote returning indented string

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def bear_room():
    print("""There is a bear here
    The bear has a bunch of honey
    The fat bear is in front of another door
    How are you going to move the bear?
    """)
```

And it returns the following:

```
There is a bear here
    The bear has a bunch of honey
    The fat bear is in front of another door
    How are you going to move the bear?
```

Can anyone advise how I can get rid of the indentation on lines 2, 3, and 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2504457/1869597

One of your options is to use implicit concatenation:

```
def bear_room():
    print(
        "There is a bear here\n"
        "The bear has a bunch of honey\n"
        "The fat bear is in front of another door\n"
        "How are you going to move the bear?"
    )
```

Comment: I think you want to indent the other strings such that the first `"` align

Comment: Thanks Jordan..however using your code returned one long sentence. I added \n to the end of each line which did the trick. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Yes, `\n` should be added at the end of each line. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify that string literal (for example, it's defined outside of your code), use [`inspect.cleandoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc) or equivalent:

```
In [2]: import inspect

In [3]: s = inspect.cleandoc("""There is a bear here
   ...:     The bear has a bunch of honey
   ...:     The fat bear is in front of another door
   ...:     How are you going to move the bear?
   ...: """)

In [4]: print(s)
There is a bear here
The bear has a bunch of honey
The fat bear is in front of another door
How are you going to move the bear?
```

If you can modify it, it's much easier to remove leading spaces manually:

```
def bear_room():
    print("""There is a bear here
The bear has a bunch of honey
The fat bear is in front of another door
How are you going to move the bear?
""")
```

or use implicit [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

```
def bear_room():
    print('There is a bear here\n'
          'The bear has a bunch of honey\n'
          'The fat bear is in front of another door\n'
          'How are you going to move the bear?\n')
```

This option will produce expected results if you end strings with newline characters (`\n`).

Answer (score 2):

One can use the [dedent](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) function. The following solution has the 3 advantages

- one does not have to add `\n` character at the end of each line, the text can directly be copied from extern source,
- one can keep the indentation of our function,
- no extra line are inserted before and after of the text

The function looks like this:

```
from textwrap import dedent
dedentString = lambda s : dedent(s[1:])[:-1]

def bear_room():
    s="""
    There is a bear here
    The bear has a bunch of honey
    The fat bear is in front of another door
    How are you going to move the bear?
    """
    print("Start of string : ")
    print(dedentString(s))
    print("End of string")

bear_room()
```

The result is :

```
Start of string :
There is a bear here
The bear has a bunch of honey
The fat bear is in front of another door
How are you going to move the bear?
End of string
```

Comment: instead of using `dedunt(s[1:])[:-1]` you can use `dedunt(s).strip()`

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, after the first line, there is indentation - the indentation inside the triple quoted string is whitespace. So you need to remove those.

The following works:

```
def bear_room():
    print("""There is a bear here
The bear has a bunch of honey
The fat bear is in front of another door
How are you going to move the bear?""")

bear_room()
```

Comment: Yes, that also works! However for the purpose of keeping the code tidy, I would stick with Jordan's answer above. Because all the code under 'print' resides within the 'bear_room' function. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, if it helps, you can upvote more than one answers.