# EOL SyntaxError in python

Tags: python

I have a SyntaxError:EOL while scanning string literal in line 3

```
def main(): 
encoded = "
غيعاژ هرظف
 "

english_frequences = [
    14, 4.2, o.7, 5.2, 0.1, 1.2, 0.4,
    1, 1.4, 7.5, 0.1, 8.5, 2.1, 0.1,
    3.3, 2.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 1.5,
    0.2, 1.6, 1.2, 3, 1.7, 2.7, 5.7, 7.1, 6, 5.7, 9.1]

(key, decoded) = vigenere_decrypt(english_frequences, encoded)
```

Comment: use triple quote or single line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings

Comment: Unrelated to your current error: `o.7` is probably not going to work.

Comment: thank you.
when I did that it has SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file main.py on line 78, but no encoding declared;

Comment: That error comes from Python 2. Please use Python 3 as it is far superior when it comes to Unicode text; the command is `python3` in Linux/MacOSX

Comment: @viol please ask another question for another question instead.

Comment: thanks taesu,Kevin and Antti Haapala

Comment: In any case, the `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character...` error is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589620/syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xa3-in-file-when-function-returns-%C2%A3); you'd need to declare your file as using the `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: do you know about importError: can not import name uppercase in python3?

Comment: `string.uppercase` is called `string.ascii_uppercase` in Python 3, because that is what it is.