# Python: Should I use multiple print statements or "+" for consecutive sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    print("\nINSTRUCTIONS~\nEnter:\n'c' to use a full fledged calculator,")
    print("'a' to add and subtract numbers " +
          "(faster than calculator if you just want to add and subtract),")
    print("'s' to find a number's square root,")
    print("'p' to see powers,")
    print("'n' to arrange numbers in ascending and descending order,")
    print("'f' to calculate factorials,\n'x' to exit the program,")
```

I currently put a "+" for sentences on the same line, but otherwise make another print statement, I would like to know which would be a better programming practice.

Comment: This would be the perfect use for a multi line string.

Comment: @MorganThrapp meaning + right?

Comment: Nope, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings

Comment: You can use `""" your text"""`

Comment: But this wouldn't be very readable if I had the print tabbed in like 4 times since I'd have to make the docstring to the utmost left to prevent it from showing the blank spaces from tabbing in the code on the screen.

Comment: @NeelKamath: Triple-quoted strings and docstrings are different concepts. A docstring is a string that appears as its own as the first statement of a function, class, or module, and is used as the `__doc__` attribute of the thing it documents. Whether a string uses triple quotes is unconnected to whether it's a docstring.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, they are essentially the same. It is really a matter of readability, and thus personal preference.

However, there is a more convenient way to do it, which is to use [multi line strings](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). They are delimited by `"""`, and are essentially strings that are capable of spanning multiple lines.

For example,

```
print("Hello,
world!")
```

would throw an error saying `EOL while scanning string literal`, whereas

```
print("""Hello,
world!""")
```

is fine and prints this:

```
Hello,
World!
```

as it is supposed to.

---

Clarification: It is **not** the same as using the line continuation character(`\`). That only goes to the next line without breaking the string, to help the programmer read their code. It does not include the newline.

This:

```
print("Hello,\
world!")
```

Is not the same as this:

```
print("""Hello,
world!""")
```

While it is true they are both valid, they have different results. The former would print:

```
Hello,world!
```

While the latter would print

```
Hello,
world!
```

---

**EDIT:**
When using this for a docstring, there is the concern that indentation meant for human readability will interfere with it by adding in extra tabs. Example:

```
# Less easily readable
def test():
    """Docstring
Docstring"""
    pass

# More easily readable
def otherTest():
    """Docstring
    Docstring"""
    pass
```

The thing is that these two docstrings produce the exact same result. Python ignores the leading whitespace.

---

Source:
[Proper indentation for Python multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings)

Comment: But the docstrings insert the tabs I have and the only way to get past that is to not tab in the lines but I feel that would hinder readability.

Comment: @NeelKamath As far as I know there's no way around that

Comment: But..there is a difference (when printed).

Comment: I guess I'll just do this:
    print("hello "
            "there "
            "hi ")
(each " " being on a separate line immediately below the first)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of speed they are equivalent.

```
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'

size = 5


def test_multiple_prints():
    for _ in range(size):
        print(text)


def test_single_print():
    big_text = '\n'.join([text for _ in range(size)])
    print(big_text)


%timeit test_multiple_prints()
#1000 loops, best of 3: 702 µs per loop


%timeit test_single_print()
#1000 loops, best of 3: 703 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Do whatever makes the program easiest to read and easiest to maintain.