# Proper indentation for the second line of a multiline code with parentheses

Tags: python, indentation, multiline, parentheses, pep8

**What is the recommended standard indentation for the second line of a multiline Python code with parentheses/commas?**

1. No indentation:

   ```
   plt.imshow(np.transpose(Z), extent=[0,4.2,0,48000], cmap='jet',
   vmin=-100, vmax=0, origin='lowest', aspect='auto')
   ```
2. 4 spaces indentation:

   ```
   plt.imshow(np.transpose(Z), extent=[0,4.2,0,48000], cmap='jet',
       vmin=-100, vmax=0, origin='lowest', aspect='auto')
   ```
3. Identation up to the `(`:

   ```
   plt.imshow(np.transpose(Z), extent=[0,4.2,0,48000], cmap='jet',
              vmin=-100, vmax=0, origin='lowest', aspect='auto')
   ```
4. Another solution?

This is linked: [Proper indentation for Python multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings) but here the question is specific to multiline with parentheses / commas, and not strings.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer @FHTMitchell? (I didn't know this 8-spaces rule!)

Answer (score 4):

I would never use options 1 or 2, they can be misleading. 3 is good if you have enough room.

There is one more option which can be used when option 3 leaves too little room or when splitting lines using a backslash (PyCharm defaults to this in the latter situation), **two indentation levels (8 spaces)**:

```
plt.imshow(np.transpose(Z), extent=[0,4.2,0,48000], cmap='jet',
        vmin=-100, vmax=0, origin='lowest', aspect='auto')

def grouper_with_prev(iterable: _Iin[_T], n: int, include_first: bool = False) \
        -> _Iout[_t.Tuple[_T, ...]]:
    """
    Returns n size chuncks of iterable with the previous n-1 elements

    """
    ...
```

This doesn't have the confusion of options 1 and 2, making it obvious what you're doing.

Comment: Agree. 3 looks the best, but sometimes there is no room.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow [PEP8, Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) then I would go with option 3:

```
# Aligned with opening delimiter.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)
```

I personally really like this option as it makes things clearer to read for myself and others. But if you are working at a company make sure to check with the company standards (each company might have their preference).

Comment: Go to the code layout part on this link: https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ and check `# Aligned with opening delimiter.`

Comment: @Bazingaa you're right! I included it in the answer for completeness.