# Convert string to type of stdin or as a file would be imported?

Tags: python, string, input, type-conversion, stdin

**How can a multi-line string be converted to the type that stdin or an imported file is?**

I would like to define a few multi-line strings in the code that can be interpreted as if they were imported from a file or stdin. The reason being I want the text to be in the code and not a separate file.

I would like a solution to the pseudo `X = convert(string)` below so that the two `parse` results in the same thing.

```
input = Open(file.txt)
string = """Hello
             world!"""

X = convert(string)

parse(input)
parse(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
from io import StringIO

string = """Hello
world!"""

X = StringIO(string)
print(X.readlines()) # Example file operation
# ['Hello\n', 'world!']
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other way to define a multi-line string than with ´"""string"""´? For aesthetic purposes, it would be nice to align ´Hello´ with ´world!´.

Comment: @Defindun Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings).

Comment: I recommend using `textwrap.dedent()` so that you can indent triple quoted strings in a natural fashion.