# Align multiple functions in text file python

Tags: python

I am trying to write multiple functions to a file based on user input. Here the problem is the code which write to a file, is not left aligned. maybe missing few basic elements.

Here is the code:

```
import requests

G=input("Define Count")
for k in range(0,G):
perf=G

if k==0 :
        string = """
            ### RUN ####
            def run():
                d = collections.OrderedDict()
                d['run']= 123,
                return d
            URL = "https://..../run"
            headers  = {"Content-Type":"application/json",
                        "Authorization": Token}
            payload = json.dumps([run() for n in range(%s)])
            resp = requests.post(URL, headers = headers ,data = payload))
            if resp.status_code = 200:
                print('Fail: ' + str(resp.status_code)+ str(resp.text))
            else:
                print('Pass' + str(resp.status_code)+ str(resp.text))
                """
            string = Template % (Perf)
            with open(path, 'a') as f:
                f.write(string)
elif k==1:
         string = """
            ### STOP ####
            def stop():
                d = collections.OrderedDict()
                d['STOP']= 123,
                d['wait']=20
                return d
            URL = "https://..../stop"
            headers  = {"Content-Type":"application/json",
                        "Authorization": Token}
            payload = json.dumps([stop() for n in range(%s)])
            resp = requests.post(URL, headers = headers ,data = payload))
            if resp.status_code = 200:
                print('Fail: ' + str(resp.status_code)+ str(resp.text))
            else:
                print('Pass' + str(resp.status_code)+ str(resp.text))
                """
            string = Template % (Perf)
            with open(path, 'a') as f:
                f.write(string)
  elfif k=.....
```

when execute in loop, I expect the output file after write, with left aligned as :

```
   def run():
            ....
            ....
   def stop():
           ....
           ....
   def wait():
           ....
```

but when i excute in loop, i do get as :

```
   def run():
            ....
            ....
           def stop():
                      ....
                      ....
       def run():
              ....
              ....
              def stop():
                       ....
                       ....
```

Am not sure why i get with irregular indent. pls help me

Comment: Are you sure creating functions is the best way to go about this? You can't just have the functions accept another argument to alter their behavior or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper indentation for Python multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-python-multiline-strings)

Comment: You may be able to use the [`textwrap.dedent()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to do what is needed. If your question contained a [mre], showing how to do this could be provided…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see couple of major logical issues with the code you shared.

1. All conditions are stated as = instead of ==

   ```
       # For Example,
       if k=0 :   # This is wrong
       if k == 0: # This is correct for the comparison
   ```
2. I am not seeing proper indentation in your code. Hopefully its copy paste issue.
3. For your logic you can create an excellent function pointers map.
   For example

   ```
   def func1():
     print('func1')

   def func2():
     print('func2')

   funcs_map = {}
   funcs_map[1] = func1
   funcs_map[2] = func2


   for i in range(10);
     if i in funcs_map.keys():
         func_ptr = funcs_map[i]
         func_ptr()

   # The above approach would be easy to manage to it will help you debug
   # instead of hardcoding functionality within string.
   ```

Good luck and see if above suggested fixed your issue.