# curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed in local host

Tags: python, sockets, curl

I was trying to build a basic socket connection and to test it with curl . The code is given below:

```
import socket

HOST,PORT='',8888

listen_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST,PORT)) 
listen_socket.listen(1)
print(f"Serving HTTP on port {PORT} ...")

while True:
    client_connection,client_address=listen_socket.accept() 
    request_data=client_connection.recv(1024)
    print(request_data.decode('utf-8'))

    http_response = b"""\
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Hello , World !!!!!!!!!
    """
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

When I try to curl into `curl localhost:8888` insted of receiving the message "Hello World !!!!" I get this `curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`.

#### I am using manjaro linux, disabled the firewall for incoming connections. If anyone can help, please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: You need to have a blank line between the headers and the body.

Comment: Also, see [Proper indentation for multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504411/proper-indentation-for-multiline-strings). You're putting whitespace into your HTTP request before the headers start and at the front of each line.

Comment: Because of your bad multi-line string indentation, your response looks like this: `<crlf><sp><sp><sp><sp>HTTP/1.1 200 OK<crlf><sp><sp><sp><sp>Hello , World !!!!!!!!!<crlf><sp><sp><sp><sp>` Since the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` is not on the 1st line, the client (curl) misinterprets the response as an [HTTP/0.9](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) response. Fix your indentation (and your content), the response needs to look more like this instead: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK<crlf>Content-Length: 23<crlf>Connection: close<crlf><crlf>Hello , World !!!!!!!!!`